# Splitting a string, but ignoring colors

Tags: java, string, bukkit

*I want to colorize the string based on playing track's progress.*

I have this string: `&bTrackArtist &1- &aTrackTitle`
`&*` defines a color
The colorful string marks the player's completeness.
Remaining part is colored gray - `&8` 
Of course, colors and messages have to be configurable

**My current solution (bad)**

Does the job, but is:

1. ugly
2. full of hardcoded values

```
String text = String.format("%s - %s", artist, title);
                
double completed = new Double(currentlyPlaying.getProgress_ms()) / new Double(duration);
int len = (int)(text.length() * completed);

String prettyText = ChatColor.AQUA + artist.substring(0, Math.min(len, artist.length())) +
    (len > artist.length() ? ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + " - ".substring(0, Math.min(len - artist.length(), 3)) : "") +
    (len > artist.length() + 3 ? ChatColor.GREEN + title.substring(0, Math.min(len - artist.length() - 3, title.length())) : "");

// return prettyText + ChatColor.GRAY + text.substring(len);
```

`ChatColor` is another way to color text

Answer (score 0):

You should determine where the remaining color should start, then use `substring` as you did.

If you want to remove color in the `text` string, you can use [`ChatColor.stripColor`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#stripColor(java.lang.String)).

You can do like this:

```java
String text = String.format("%s - %s", artist, title);
ChatColor colorDone = ChatColor.GREEN, colorRemain = ChatColor.DARK_GRAY; // set color
// should be a percent value
double completed = new Double(currentlyPlaying.getProgress_ms()) / new Double(duration);
int slot = (int) (completed * s.length()) / 100; // A cross multiplication

String prettyText = colorDone + s.substring(0, slot) + colorRemain + s.substring(slot, s.length());
```

Comment: i think you missed a thing - the colored string has multiple colors, look closely at my snip

Comment: @Minecon724 Sorry but I didn't know what you were asking, can you show expected result ?

Comment: artists name is aqua, track title is green and the separator - dark blue